# Meta analysis: rma vs. metaprop (funnel plot-related)

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I have a problem, which is beyond my ability to solve.

So, I am trying to use two different meta analysis functions (in R): rma and metaprop.

In case of rma,

```
meta.dat.2 <- escalc(xi   = Favorable, 
                     ni   = Patients, 
                     data = meta.dat.2, 
                     add  = 0,
                     measure = "PFT")

subganal.moderator <- rma(yi, vi, 
                          data = meta.dat.2, 
                          mods = ~ Binary_Type, 
                          method = "DL") 

funnel(subganal.moderator, main="Standard Error",
       atransf=transf.ipft.hm, targ = list(ni=meta.dat.2$Patients))
```

Then I get the following funnel plot:
[image]

Now, I thought that the next code using metaprop would produce the same result.
(Mainly because I used the same options, "PFT" and "DL". And they have the same moderator.)
However, unfortunately it did not.

```
pes.summary <- metaprop(Favorable, Patients, 
                        studlab = Study, 
                        data    = meta.dat.2, 
                        sm      = "PFT", 
                        byvar   = Binary_Type, 
                        method.tau = "DL",
                        tau.common = TRUE)

funnel(pes.summary, 
       comb.fixed = TRUE, comb.random = FALSE)
```

And the funnel plot generated is:
[image]

I REALLY CANNOT UNDERSTAND WHY I GET TWO DIFFERENT FUNNEL PLOTS, EVEN THOUGH THE OPTIONS ARE THE SAME.

Can someone help me???

Thank you in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top plot uses the residuals from the meta-regression which hence take account of the moderator variable. The bottom plot uses the (transformed) effect size so the plot looks slightly different. Since the plot do not look that different I would suspect the moderator was not having a huge effect.

I think if you want more detail behind the choices the authors have made you might do better to ask on the mailing list dedicated to meta-analysis in R https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// where authors of both the packages you are using post from time to time.

Comment: Hi @mdewey! Thank you for helping me again :-)
I believe that (as far as I know) by having "byvar" option in metaprop, we take account into the moderator variable. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

By looking at the plots only, is the first one (using rma) looking better?

Comment: In fact I think it does an analysis for sub-sets but I do not use meta so I may be wrong. I think you have to use metagen to get the usual meta-regression estimates